# HydraIRC - Save settings between sessions (minimize to system tray)

Tags: windows-7, irc

I recently started using the HydraIRC client and I want the application minimized to the system tray most of the time.

I go to *Options > Prefs > Advanced > Booleans > Minimize to SysTray* and it works, but this setting seems to be reset every time I open the application.

Is there a way to save settings when I close the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around I found the answer to this. It seems that **Windows 7 doesn't allow programs to write to the *Program Files (x86)* directory**.

Move your HydraIRC folder into C:\ or another writeable location and settings will be saved fine.

Comment: It's enough to run HydraIRC as administrator. You don't need to move the folder. Just tested it now and it works.